# XHR ontimeout() in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking for a way to run a function when a $http call gets a timeout. There's and event handler in XMLHttpRequest called [ontimeout](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#handler-xhr-ontimeout) but I can't find a way to do this in AnguarJS with $http. Any solutions?

```
$http.get('http://10.255.255.1/test', {withCredentials: true})
  .then(function(response, error) {
    console.log('then');
    console.log(response, error);
  })
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(status, data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(status, data);
  });
```

None of them are called in this case. Also it seems it's not GET which is timing out but OPTIONS.

Comment: That case don't fall in the fail callback? `$http.get(url).then(success, fail)` you can read the status from the callback parameters: `function(data, status, headers, config)`. If you want something global you can register an interceptor

Comment: I usually use .success and .error, but also just tried then, none of them returns anything if there's a timeout/connection problem.

Comment: Looks like a bug, can you give me the url you use so I can play with it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I've added the $http call. jsFiddle doesn't support $http calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use .then() you lose the success/error callbacks that are $http specific, can you try:

```
$http.get('http://10.255.255.1/test', {withCredentials: true})
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('then');
    console.log(response);
  }, function(response) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(response);
  });
```

or

```
$http.get('http://10.255.255.1/test', {withCredentials: true})
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(status, data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(status, data);
  });
```

Comment: I did try .error-.success and .then separately, but the error-callback didn't work on the timeout. It works with .then though! Thanks